# Swift: Other gestures are blocking default iOS 13 modal drag to dismiss gesture

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uigesturerecognizer

I am modally presenting a complex view that itself has a number of gestures implemented. The entire experience was built in SwiftUI (although the modal is presented via UIKit). Anyway, I would like the default "drag down to dismiss" gesture (as of iOS 13) to be recognized by the modal, but the gestures used in the view presented by the modal are overriding the drag gesture. Is there any way to make the drag gesture a higher priority so that it is picked up before the other gestures? How do I access that gesture anyway?